# Azure Blob Storage Deployment: Stored Access Policy gets deleted

Tags: azure-devops, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-resource-manager, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

**Context:**

I deploy a storage account as well as one or more containers with the following ARM template with Azure DevOps respectively a Resource Deployment Task:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "storageAccountName": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The name of the Azure Storage account."
      }
    },
    "containerNames": {
      "type": "array",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The names of the blob containers."
      }
    },
    "location": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The location in which the Azure Storage resources should be deployed."
      }
    }
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "name": "[parameters('storageAccountName')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
      "apiVersion": "2018-07-01",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "kind": "StorageV2",
      "sku": {
        "name": "Standard_LRS",
        "tier": "Standard"
      },
      "properties": {
        "accessTier": "Hot"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "[concat(parameters('storageAccountName'), '/default/', parameters('containerNames')[copyIndex()])]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices/containers",
      "apiVersion": "2018-03-01-preview",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[parameters('storageAccountName')]"
      ],
      "copy": {
        "name": "containercopy",
        "count": "[length(parameters('containerNames'))]"
      }
    }
  ],
  "outputs": {
    "storageAccountName": {
      "type": "string",
      "value": "[parameters('storageAccountName')]"
    },
    "storageAccountKey": {
      "type": "string",
      "value": "[listKeys(parameters('storageAccountName'), '2018-02-01').keys[0].value]"
    },
    "storageContainerNames": {
      "type": "array",
      "value": "[parameters('containerNames')]"
    }
  }
}
```

Input can be e.g.

```
-storageAccountName 'stor1' -containerNames [ 'con1', 'con2' ] -location 'westeurope'
```

In an next step I create Stored Access Policies for the containers deployed.

**Problem:**

The first time I do that everything works fine. But if I execute the pipeline a second time the Stored Access Policies gets deleted by the deployment of the template. The storage account itself with its containers and blobs are not deleted (as it should be). This is unfortunate because I want to keep the Stored Access Policy with its starttime and expirytime as deployed the first time, furthermore I expect that the SAS also become invalid (not tested so far).

**Questions:**

Why is this happening?
How can I avoid this problem respectively keep the Stored Access Policies?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some investigation this seems to be by design. When deploying ARM templates for storage accounts the PUT operation is used, i.e. elements that are not specified within the template are removed. As it is not possible to specify Shared Access Policies for containers within an ARM template for Storage Accounts existing ones get deleted when the template is redeployed...